# How to create a gridview, but the listview values comes from a Json

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview

I have a question about getting values from JSON stored on my website.  To summarize I've used Retrofit, ModelView, and Repository to obtain those values, but what happens is my GridView not filling with contents.  There is no error as it complies with completion.  The url for the file is: https://www.androidparadise.site/shop-categories/ and  a single Json object is:

```
   [
     {
       "category": "Clothes",
       "image": "R.drawable.ic_baseline_shopping",
       "stores" : [
       {"name": "Macy's", "url": "www.macys.com"},
       {"name": "Amazon", "url": "www.amazon.com"}
       ]
     }
  ]
```

// Used JSon to Kotlin class plugin to provide this data class

```
    data class ShoppingCategoriesDataClass(
    val category: String,
    val image: Int,
    val stores: List<Store>

   )

   interface ShoppingCategoriesInterface {

      @GET("/shop-categories/")
      suspend fun getAllCategoriesIcons() : Response<List<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>>
   }
```

A sample of my Appmodule is:

```
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://www.androidparadise.site"

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideShoppingCategoriesApi() : ShoppingCategoriesInterface {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl((BASE_URL))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ShoppingCategoriesInterface::class.java)
    }
```

ShopCategoryRepositoryImpl

```
    class ShopCategoryRepositoryImpl(private val categoryApi: 
    ShoppingCategoriesInterface, 
    val app: Application): ShopCategoryRepository {
    override suspend fun getAllCategoriesIcons(): 
       Resource<List<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>> {
        return try{
            val response = categoryApi.getAllCategoriesIcons()
            val result = response.body()

            if (response.isSuccessful && result != null){

                Resource.Success(result)
            }
            else{
                Resource.Error(response.message())
            }

        }catch(e: Exception){
            Resource.Error(e.message ?: "An error occurred")
        }
    }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.tritongames.shopwishlist.R
    import com.tritongames.shopwishlist.data.models.ShoppingCategoriesDataClass
    import javax.inject.Inject

class RecyclerViewAdapter @Inject constructor(private var categoryList: 
   ArrayList<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>): 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecylerViewHolder>() {
    class RecylerViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var tv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoriesText)
        var iv: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoriesPic)
    }



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecylerViewHolder {
       val view: View = 
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.wish_layout, parent)
        return RecylerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecylerViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.tv.text = categoryList[position].category
        holder.iv.setImageResource(categoryList[position].image)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categoryList.size

    }

}
```

Finally, the MainActivity called Shop

```
   @AndroidEntryPoint
   class Shop : AppCompatActivity() {

    val recipientVM: RecipientViewModel by viewModels()
    val shoppingVM: ShoppingDataViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var newCategoryList: ArrayList<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop)

        mName = ArrayList<String>()
        spinName = findViewById(R.id.spinName)

        lifecycleScope.launch() {
            recipientVM.recipientLoad.collect{
                event->
                    when(event){
                        is RecipientViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Success ->{

                            nameAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@Shop, 
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                recipientVM.loadRecipientNames()
                            )
                        }
                        is RecipientViewModel.RecipientLoadingEvent.Failure ->{

                        }`



`
                        else -> Unit
                    }

            }
        }

        spinName?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            @Override
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?,
                                        position: Int, id: Long) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                val selected_name: String = spinName!!.selectedItem.toString()

            }

            @Override
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }

        w1Text = findViewById(R.id.wish1Text)
        w2Text = findViewById(R.id.wish2Text)
        w3Text = findViewById(R.id.wish3Text)
        category1 = findViewById(R.id.wish1Cat)
        category2 = findViewById(R.id.wish2Cat)
        category3 = findViewById(R.id.wish3Cat)

        nextBTN = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonNext)
        nextBTN?.setOnClickListener { // click to jump to next class WishList
          val wlIntent = Intent(this@Shop, WishList::class.java)
            startActivity(wlIntent)
        }


        lifecycleScope.launch {
           shoppingVM.shopDataLoad.collect{event->
               when(event){
                   is ShoppingDataViewModel.ShopDataLoadEvent.Success ->{

                       val recView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recViewGrid)
                       val catList = shoppingVM.getCategoryList()
                       val recViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter( getUserData(catList))
                       val gLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@Shop, 3)
                       recView.layoutManager = gLayoutManager
                       recView.adapter = recViewAdapter
                   }
                   is ShoppingDataViewModel.ShopDataLoadEvent.Error ->{
                       Resource.Error<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>("Error Loading 
                   Categories")

                   }
                   else -> Unit
              }

           }


        }

        val cDragListener1 = Category1DragEventListener()
        val cDragListener2 = Category2DragEventListener()
        val cDragListener3 = Category3DragEventListener()
        category1?.setOnDragListener(cDragListener1)
        category2?.setOnDragListener(cDragListener2)
        category3?.setOnDragListener(cDragListener3)
        cLongClickListener = CategoryOnItemLongClickListener()
        gv?.onItemLongClickListener = cLongClickListener
    }

        private fun getUserData(catList: List<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass>): 
        ArrayList<ShoppingCategoriesDataClass> {
        for (i in catList.indices){
            val category = ShoppingCategoriesDataClass(catList[i].category, 
        catList[i].image, listOf())
            newCategoryList.add(category)

        }
          return newCategoryList

       }
```